# Why can't I remove the Ord Typeclass from this haskell implementation of Kadane's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, types, type-inference, type-systems

I have been implementing kadane's algorithm in haskell, AFAIK it is working correctly

```
kadane' :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> a
kadane' xs = head$ foldl maxsub [0,0] xs

maxsub :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> a -> [a]
maxsub x y
    | last(x)+y > head(x) = if last(x)+y > 0 then [last(x)+y, last(x)+y] else [last(x)+y, 0]
    | otherwise = if last(x)+y > 0 then [head(x), last(x)+y]  else [head(x), 0]
```

I want to remove Ord typeclass from function's type specification, since I can't find maximum sub array for all the types that can be ordered. But I can't get rid of the Ord typeclass from the type specification. I wrote them initially by asking haskell's type inference as shown below

```
*Main> :t kadane' 
kadane' :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> a
*Main> :t maxsub 
maxsub :: (Ord a, Num a) => [a] -> a -> [a]
*Main>
```

If I remove Ord Typeclass as shown below

```
kadane' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
kadane' xs = head$ foldl maxsub [0,0] xs

maxsub :: (Num a) => [a] -> a -> [a]
maxsub x y
    | last(x)+y > head(x) = if last(x)+y > 0 then [last(x)+y, last(x)+y] else [last(x)+y, 0]
    | otherwise = if last(x)+y > 0 then [head(x), last(x)+y]  else [head(x), 0]
```

and compiling the above code throws the following error

```
*Main> :l kadanes.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( kadanes.hs, interpreted )

kadanes.hs:6:21:
    Could not deduce (Ord a) arising from a use of ‘>’
    from the context (Num a)
      bound by the type signature for maxsub :: Num a => [a] -> a -> [a]
      at kadanes.hs:4:11-36
    Possible fix:
      add (Ord a) to the context of
        the type signature for maxsub :: Num a => [a] -> a -> [a]
    In the expression: last (x) + y > head (x)
    In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                   an equation for ‘maxsub’:
      last (x) + y > head (x)
    In an equation for ‘maxsub’:
        maxsub x y
          | last (x) + y > head (x)
          = if last (x) + y > 0 then
                [last (x) + y, last (x) + y]
            else
                [last (x) + y, 0]
          | otherwise
          = if last (x) + y > 0 then
                [head (x), last (x) + y]
            else
                [head (x), 0]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

According to the Possible Fix reported in the error I need to add Ord typeclass again, What am I doing wrong ?

And also please evaluate the correctness of the algorithm, if possible suggest alternative ways

Comment: Style comment: the `maxsub` function should take `(a,a)` instead of `[a]`, since you know there will be exactly two arguments. This will also allow you to avoid dangerous partial functions like `head,last`, and simply use pattern matching to fetch those e.g. `maxsub (x1,x2) y = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot remove `Ord` since you are using functions like `<` and `>` and operating them on polymorphic type. See their type:

```
λ> :t (<)
(<) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool
```

But if you instead limit your polymorphic code to operate only on `Int` or any other monomorphic instance for which `Ord` instance is already defined, then you can remove it:

```
maxsub :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
maxsub x y
    | last(x)+y > head(x) = if last(x)+y > 0 then [last(x)+y, last(x)+y] else [last(x)+y, 0]
    | otherwise = if last(x)+y > 0 then [head(x), last(x)+y]  else [head(x), 0]

kadane' :: [Int] -> Int
kadane' xs = head$ foldl maxsub [0,0] xs
```